# How to find $AM$ which is a distance between two points in a mountain when looked through a binoculars?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a cartoon which represents the view of a pair of mountains when looked through a binoculars. Assuming that according to the inner ruler of the binoculars you can spot $BM=MN=4\,cm$ and $NC=6\,cm$, the inner goniometer indicates that $\angle ANC=\angle AMB=90^\circ$ and $\angle  BAM=\angle MAC$. Also it is known $A,\,M,\,N$ are colinear. With these information find the actual distance between $A$ and $M$. Assuming the scale is $\frac{1}{1000}$. Take into account that $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle ANC$ are triangles.
>
> [image: Sketch of the problem]

The choices given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{40 m}\\
2.&\textrm{50 m}\\
3.&\textrm{60 m}\\
4.&\textrm{80 m}\\
\end{array}$

I don't know exactly what to do in this problem. Can someone help me here?. I'm not sure if should I use the given relations in a right triangle or what?. It would be nice if someone could help me with **how to use the drawing given** to assign the angles and find the length that it is requested which is $AM$. But just I don't know should congruence be used here?. Can someone help me with this?. Or would it be similarity of triangles?.

**Help please! I'm lost.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first.
The 2 triangles are  similar because they share two angles in common,  so we can make the following equation:

$ \frac{BM}{AM} = \frac{NC}{AN} $

And we know that $ AN = 4 + AM $ so:

$ \frac{4}{AM} = \frac{6}{4+AM} $

Then solving this equation we get:

$ AM = 8cm $

$ AM = 8 * 1000 $ So as 1 centimeter equals 1000 centimeters

$ AM = 8000 cm $

$ AM = 80 m $

P.S You asked for help about assigning the angles, idk what do you really mean, but if you need help to know where the angles are, they're always in the point of the middle, between the two segments ( first point and middle point, middle point and last point ).
So for example, the angle ABC is in point B, and it's between segment AB and segment BC. [image: Angles]

Hope that this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for that nice explanation and welcome to Math SE! what I was referring it was that initially I did not knew where were the angles, from your drawing I can spot them. Yes this is a case of similarity of $AA$. Again thanks, maybe can you upvote my question?. I'm accepting your answer because it fully addressed my doubts.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I've already upvoted it! Ty for the welcome! Happy that I could help